# why the runfile doesn't come up with any results?

Tags: python

I'm in a very beginning level and trying some basic functions: I'm running a search inside a string to find whether it contains the letter that I input, here is the code:

```
def find(word, letter):
    index=0
    while index<len(word):
        if word[index]==letter:
            return index
        index=index+1
    return -1

word='geeksforgeeks'
find(word,'e')
```

The console of spyder doesn't come up with results but runfile, what's wrong with my program?

Comment: The returned result is not being displayed.  Try `print(find(word,'e'))`.

Answer (score 1):

`runfile` is the command to run your file, that's normal.

Now you need to print the result of your function to see it: `print(find(word, 'e'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if the letter exists in the string, just use:

```
print('e' in word)
```

Or using a function:

```
def find(word, letter):
    return 'e' in word
```

And just print the result you received from the function, calling:

```
print(find(word, letter))
```

Comment: thx for ur addition comment, and ur willing to teach me, I appreciate.

Comment: My bad, my goal is to determine whether a character is found in the string, if it is then return the index, otherwise return -1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning just print:

```
def find(word, letter):
    index=0
    while index<len(word):
        if word[index]==letter:
            return print(index)
        index=index+1
    return print(-1)

word='geeksforgeeks'
find(word,'e')
```